# Paypal integration issue on live

Tags: paypal

I am integrating paypal in android application.

There is one pair of credentials from which I am unable to login, but on the same code other pair of login/password credentials is working fine on live payment.

I want to know what could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to know what could be issue.

Your credentials could be wrong, or the login/payment could have been denied, or one of the accounts involved could be unable to send or receive payments. Those are some possibilities.

You haven't provided any specific and detailed information about the error behavior, so one can only guess.